# No wifi option available at all

Tags: wifi, networking

I'm trying my hand at ElementaryOS, but not only am I not able to get wifi to work, I'm not even seeing it as an option.  I've looked through the knowledge base and tried all of the solutions that I've found there, but none of them have worked.  Upon logging in I do not see a wifi icon in the upper right hand corner.  In addition, if I click on Network Settings, I'm not seeing a wifi option there either.  I'm using a Dell Optiplex with a Netgear a6100 Wifi dongle and the latest version of Elementary updated via a wired connection.  Being limited to a wired network connection makes this all but useless so it's quite frustrating, to say the least.

Comment: Please [edit](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/posts/26595/edit) your question to add the model name/number for your wireless dongle. Netgear makes all sorts of equipment so we can't guess what model you have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a few hours. Never used Elementary OS before. I went to `Applications > AppCenter > Installed (tab)` and installed all the updates available. Rebooted and done.